# image selector/delector android

Tags: android, ios, iphone, android-layout, ios7

I am hoping to build an image selector/de-selector in an Android app.

So far I have been able to use an image view, and display the selected image, and put a button next to the image view to deselect the image.

However I am hoping to overlay some sort of a remove button, to make it look pretty and concise, however I am trying to avoid an overlay button as such.

Any ideas please.

Secondly, I would like to filter out only certain file types.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, any comments to filter out only say jpeg images, I have tried images/jpeg, and it didn't work.

Comment: A little bit like the windows forms dialog filter, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter(v=vs.110).aspx. And any ideas if the same can be done in IOS